# Can I see which iPad apps I use most frequently?

Tags: ipad, ios, applications

I have many games on my iPad which my kids play.  I'd like to remove the games and apps that aren't used but I don't know how to find this information.

Is there a way to see the most used apps on your iOS device?  Or possibly a list of apps with a "last used" data field?

Comment: This doesn't _exactly_ answer the question, but might be partly useful. If you go to Settings -> General -> Usage, then wait for a few seconds for the list to generate, you can see a list of the apps that take up the most _space_, including both the application and its associated data. That can help when looking at which apps to consider for removal (largest first).

Answer (score 7):

In a pinch, you could look through the multitasking bar that appears when you double-click the home button. The apps are arranged in order of most recently used. It is not a measure of how frequently an app is used, but it could at least tell you if it was used recently, or if other apps have been of more interest lately.

Answer (score 4):

If you're jailbroken, you can use one of a few Cydia tweaks:

- ### App Stat

  App Stat is an extremely simple tweak which tracks how many times you've opened an app, how long you spent in the app, and the last time you opened it.

  [image]
- ### App Analytics

  A much better looking (paid) alternative to App Stat, which includes the same information and also lets you narrow down the results on a monthly basis.

  [image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no facility to do this in stock iOS. I agree, this would be useful.

The most effective way to ask Apple for this sort of thing is through their [bug reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/wa/signIn). Unfortunately, you need a (free) developer account to post a bug and you're not likely to get much of a response, so don't get your hopes up.

Answer (score 1):

In my business we reatinoalize old reports clients say they need.  At some point we reach the area called "remove it and if no one complains, you really don't use it"

Since it is so easy to put them back on the ipad, this might not be a bad approach with the games

Comment: Reatinoalize?  I'm pretty sure that's not a word.  :-)

Comment: for you...humor i provide :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always go to battery usage in settings and it will list the apps that have been used in the last 7 days and how long they have been used for.

Answer (score -1):

no unforitunetly not, however, if all of the apps which you use, all depend on data. you can use an app like [Onavo](http://www.onavo.com) to see witch app use most data, hence which app you use the "most"

This is not scientific, and results can vary because of numerous reasons but it might give you a better insight